# Java Mail, sending multiple attachments not working

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I looked at many entries on the internet without having luck.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

public class MailTest
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AddressException, MessagingException, IOException
    {
        String host = "***";
        String from = "b";
        String to = "***";

        // Get system properties
        Properties props = System.getProperties();

        // Setup mail server
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);

        // Get session
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

        // Define message
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
        message.setSubject("Hello JavaMail");
        message.setText("Welcome to JavaMail");

        // Handle attachment 1
        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart1 = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart1.attachFile("c:/Temp/a.txt");

        // Handle attachment 2
        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart2 = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart2.attachFile("c:/Temp/b.txt");

        MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");

        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart1);
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart2);

        message.setContent(multipart);

        // Send message
        Transport.send(message);
    }
}
```

The result is that i only get the first file attached.

1. I tried calling the attachFile method more than once but then it only applies the last attachment
2. I tried playing with the indexes at addBodyPart: no help

I checked the plain message and i see the other file in it with the same identifier and it is not listed in the attachments for some reason.

Any help would be appreciated,
Dave

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("mixed");
for (String str : attachment_PathList) {
    MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(str);
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(source.getName());
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
}
msg.setContent(multipart);
Transport.send(msg);
```

Comment: cant find the FileDataSource and DataHandler class. Which library is it in?

Comment: Adding a comment for the search filters because I had a slightly different symptom.  While sending through an Exchange server, no message was sent at all, even though no exceptions and no email response from the server.  It was just failing silently.  Adding the "mixed" also resolved this issue.

Comment: When I am trying this, only the first file in the list is being sent.

Answer (score 1):

```
    try
    {
        String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        String from = "sender gmail id";
        String pass = "sender password";
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); // added this line
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
        props.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        String[] to = {"receiver ids"}; // In this array you can add more ids
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        InternetAddress[] toAddress = new InternetAddress[to.length];
        // To get the array of addresses
        for( int i=0; i < to.length; i++ )
        { // changed from a while loop
            toAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(Message.RecipientType.TO);
        for( int i=0; i < toAddress.length; i++) 
        {
        // changed from a while loop
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress[i]);
        }
        message.setSubject("sending in a group");
        message.setText("Welcome to JavaMail");
        // set ur text message
        BodyPart messageBodyPart1 = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart1.setText("This is message body");
        //file path that you want to attatch
        // you are able to send multipule file simultaneously
        String filename[] ={"C:\\Documents and Settings\\admin\\Desktop\\imp data\\emil id.txt" ,"C:\\Documents and Settings\\admin\\Desktop\\imp data\\emil id.txt"};//change accordingly
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart1);
        for(int i=0 ; i<filename.length ; i++)
        {
            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart2 = new MimeBodyPart();
            DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename[i]);
            messageBodyPart2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            messageBodyPart2.setFileName(filename[i]);
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart2);
        }
        // both part add into maulti part 
        // set message content
        message.setContent(multipart);
        // Trans port the message 
        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect(host, from, pass);
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Looks good, but you could add some comments describing what you have done differently.

Comment: Hello firstly thanks for gave your attention .But I want to know you run this code and if you have any problem so please tell i will try to solve you problem .

Answer (score -1):

Just change the gmailUsername and gmailPass with actual gmail credentials. And also change the to and from address with your desired one. 
Here we have used Gmail SSL smtp port for sending mail. You can change it with your own mailing server details.

```
import java.util.*;

import javax.mail.*;

import javax.mail.internet.*;

import javax.activation.*;

/**

Author Mridul Chatterjee

 */

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;

import javax.mail.MessagingException;

import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;

import javax.mail.Session;

import javax.mail.Transport;

import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;

import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;



public class SendMail {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Properties props = new Properties();

props.put(”mail.smtp.host”, “smtp.gmail.com”);

props.put(”mail.smtp.socketFactory.port”, “465″);

props.put(”mail.smtp.socketFactory.class”,

“javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory”);

props.put(”mail.smtp.auth”, “true”);

props.put(”mail.smtp.port”, “465″);

ArrayList fileNames = new ArrayList();

fileNames.add(”C:/Write.txt”);

fileNames.add(”C:/Write1.txt”);

fileNames.add(”C:/Write2.txt”);

fileNames.add(”C:/Write3.txt”);

fileNames.add(”C:/25148.jpg”);



Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,

new javax.mail.Authenticator() {

protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {

return new PasswordAuthentication(”gmailUsername”,”gmailPass”);

}

});



try {



Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(”from@no-spam.com”));

message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,

InternetAddress.parse(”tomail@mail.com”));

message.setSubject(”Testing Subject”);

message.setText(”Dear Mail Crawler,” +

“nn No spam to my email, please!”);

     //  multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);



     //  DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);

    //   messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));

    //   messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);

       System.out.println(fileNames.size());

       Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

       BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

       for(int i=0;i            {

                System.out.println(fileNames.get(i));





                messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

                DataSource source = new FileDataSource((String)fileNames.get(i));

                messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));

                messageBodyPart.setFileName((String)fileNames.get(i));

                multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

                //message.setContent(multipart);

            }



       //multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

       message.setContent(multipart);



Transport.send(message);



System.out.println(”Mail Sent Successfully….”);



} catch (MessagingException e) {

throw new RuntimeException(e);

}

}

}
```