# Java mail - attachments && inline images

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I had a problem solved already this morning:
[Java Mail, sending multiple attachments not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970455/java-mail-sending-multiple-attachments-not-working)

This time I have a slightly more complicated problem: I would like to combine attached files with images.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

public class MailTest
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AddressException, MessagingException, IOException
    {
        String host = "***";
        String from = "***";
        String to = "***";

        // Get system properties
        Properties props = System.getProperties();

        // Setup mail server
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);

        // Get session
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

        // Define message
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
        message.setSubject("Hello JavaMail");

        // Handle attachment 1
        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart1 = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart1.attachFile("c:/Temp/a.txt");

        // Handle attachment 2
        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart2 = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart2.attachFile("c:/Temp/b.txt");

        FileDataSource fileDs = new FileDataSource("c:/Temp/gti.jpeg");
        MimeBodyPart imageBodypart = new MimeBodyPart();
        imageBodypart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fileDs));
        imageBodypart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<myimg>");
        imageBodypart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.INLINE);

        // Handle text
        String body = "<html><body>Elotte<img src=\"cid:myimg\" width=\"600\" height=\"90\" alt=\"myimg\" />Utana</body></html>";

        MimeBodyPart textPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        textPart.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"");
        textPart.setContent(body, "text/html; charset=utf-8");

        MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("mixed");

        multipart.addBodyPart(textPart);
        multipart.addBodyPart(imageBodypart);
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart1);
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart2);

        message.setContent(multipart);

        // Send message
        Transport.send(message);
    }
}
```

When I open the email in Gmail everything is fine: I have the two attachments, and the image is displayed in the content of the mail (in the img tag).

The problem is with Thunderbird and with RoundCubic webmail: each one showing like the image is missing and displaying it in the bottom as attachment.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Microsoft Outlook 2010 does not allow inline-images anymore! Is this a heavy Problem for you?

Comment: Well i was not using Outlook but Thunderbird. Before i changed the multipart from "related" to "mixed" it was working. Pls. see the linked stackoverflow question.

Comment: So i got this sorted out using this:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/reference/mail.html

Spring is doing the trick in the background.

But i can't close the question because my rep is not high enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite convient is also the use of ImageHtmlEmail from the [org.apache.commons.mail library](http://commons.apache.org/email/). (UPDATE: it is only included in the snapshot of 1.3) For example:

```
  HtmlEmail email = new ImageHtmlEmail();
  email.setHostName("mail.myserver.com");
  email.addTo("jdoe@somewhere.org", "John Doe");
  email.setFrom("me@apache.org", "Me");
  email.setSubject("Test email with inline image");

  // embed the image and get the content id
  URL url = new URL("http://www.apache.org/images/asf_logo_wide.gif");
  String cid = email.embed(url, "Apache logo");

  // set the html message
  email.setHtmlMsg(htmlEmailTemplate, new File("").toURI().toURL(), false);
```

Answer (score 1):

So i got this sorted out by letting the javamail go and use the spring wrapper:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/reference/mail.html

I don't know what magic it is doing in the background but it works.

Thanks for everybody!