# How to send private companies' emails with attchments directly from Java code?

Tags: java, outlook

I am curious is there any way to send emails with attachments directly from Java code. The email belongs to the company `mylogin`@companyxxx.com` I.e. manipulate Outlook using Java? Or maybe I do not need to manipulate Outlook, and it is enough to have login and password and other staff...

Comment: If you're not fussed about using Outlook, you can use JavaMail, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16117365/sending-mail-attachment-using-java) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177616/how-to-attach-multiple-files-to-an-email-using-javamail) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8973026/java-mail-attachments-inline-images)

Comment: Thank you ... The only problem is that this is a kind of confidential email system ... so i have no idea how to reach to it other than using Outlook ... These examples mainly address regular gmail etc - - - public mailboxes

Comment: Mail still needs to be sent to a smtp or imap server for distribution, so even if it was an internal mail server, the process would be the same...not sure about exchange though...

Comment: Exchange can be setup to accept smtp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do that using [javamail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html), you can download jar from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavamailjar.htm) . For outlook, you just have to set properties as follows:

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.user", username);
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.live.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
    props.put("mail.debug", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.EnableSSL.enable", "true");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "587");
```

Or if you want full example, use the method below:

```
    public int sendMailWithAttachment(String to, String subject, String body, String filepath, String sendFileName) {
    final String username = "YOUR EMAIL";
    final String password = "YOUR PWD";
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.user", username);
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.live.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
    props.put("mail.debug", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.EnableSSL.enable", "true");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "587");
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
    });
    try {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to));
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(body);
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        BodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        htmlPart.setContent("<html><body>HELLO</body></html>", "text/html");
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filepath);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(sendFileName);
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        multipart.addBodyPart(htmlPart);
        message.setContent(multipart);
        Transport.send(message);
        return 1;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```